# Showing that $\left|x-1+\frac 1{1+x}-\left(y-1+\frac 1{1+y}\right)\right|\leq 2|x-y|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I asked a question here the other day and one of the steps in the answer I encountered was: $$\left|x-1+\frac 1{1+x}-\left(y-1+\frac 1{1+y}\right)\right|\leq 2|x-y|$$

when $x,y\ge0$

I can't seem to figure out why this is true.. Cans someone help me out?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have thanks to the triangular inequality
\begin{align*}\left|x-1+\frac 1{1+x}-\left(y-1+\frac 1{1+y}\right)\right|&= 
\left|x-1+\frac 1{1+x}-y+1-\frac 1{1+y}\right|\\
&=\left|x+\frac 1{1+x}-y-\frac 1{1+y}\right|\\
&\leq |x-y|+\left|\frac 1{1+x}-\frac 1{1+y}\right|\\
&= |x-y|+\left|\frac {1+y-(1+x)}{(1+x)(1+y)}\right|\\
&=|x-y|+\frac {|y-x|}{(1+x)(1+y)}\\
&\leq 2|x-y|.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach. Let
$$
f(x)=x-1+\frac{1}{x+1}\quad\text{so that}\quad f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\,.
$$
Then $0\le f'(x)<1$ for all $x\ge0$. If $x,y\ge0$, by the mean value theorem
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)(x-y)|<|x-y|\,,
$$
where $c$ is a point between $x$ and $y$.